# Can I estimate fire temperature from a building's colour?

Tags: building-design, fire

I am studying a building that was impacted by a fire (from a Natural Hazard perspective, so consider my engineering skills as inexistant!!). There are obvious changes in the outside paint's colour, with the yellow one being original. Can anyone think of an idea of constraining temperature ranges to which the walls were exposed? Or to any relevant literature?

[image]

Comment: No, because you don't have any idea of the wall construction and what interior coverings etc were in place.

Comment: Thanks for the constructive discussion

Comment: `yellow one being original` ... green may be the original that was painted over with yellow ... you may be asking about estimating fire temperature based on peeling paint

Comment: In my experience ,temperature can be estimated from heat damage to metals , steel, copper, brass, aluminum ,zinc. Generally the examination is more focused on finding an origin to help identify a cause.

Comment: Thank you @jsotola and blacksmith37. This house was affected by several lava flows that, at some point, ignited a fire. I am trying to reconstruct the sequence of impacts, and for the thermal part the difference between radiative (from the lava) and conductive heat transfer. Since there are evidences of different gradients, I was wondering if I could roughly constrain temperature ranges at different parts of the building.